# Yarn kills Executors for exceeding memory limit during saveAsNewApihadoopFile

Tags: apache-spark

I'm currently trying to bulk load data into HBase from Spark and am primarily working with the following examples:

http://www.opencore.com/blog/2016/10/efficient-bulk-load-of-hbase-using-spark/
http://zeyuanxy.github.io/hbase_bulk_loading/

However my aggregation of the data at the start is a fair bit more complex.

The source files are about 40GB of AVRO Records with a fair number of (possibly null) fields (>200). My whole thing runs through but during saveAsNewApihadoopFile containers start getting killed by for exceeding memory limits. I have tried higher numbers of partitions (up to 4000) but still i get containers failing the same happens when I give the executors more memory (4 GB each). Also i get very high GC times which then in turn makes the whole thing awefuly slow.

Here are some questions:

Does anyone know how I could further profile the job to find out exactly why the executors need so much memory? Or what I could do to mitigate it?

Do I need to execute an action first before calling saveAsNewApihadoopFile to narrow down the problem and maybe avoid needless redistribution of data(part of my workflow is a repartitionAndSortWithinPartition)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could try to tune `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` and "memory fraction"-related settings.

Regarding profiling, there are few options that depend on how close you can get to actual nodes and their jvms and logs:

- If it's possible, try to enable JMX on executors JVMs and connect to any of them with tool like VisualVM to be able to see actual stats.
- In case of limited access you can do or request memory dumps from executor JVM.
- And last resort - enable memory profiling via `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` and adjust it with next options (check if they are suitable for GC of your choice):

`-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy  -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark`
so you will be able to have diagnostic output in your executor logs.